# mysql db for time-temperature values

Tags: mysql, datetime, temperature

I need your help to build my db the right way.

I need to store time-temperature values for different rooms of my house
and I want to use DyGraph to graph the data sets.
I want to implement different time windows: 1 hour, 24 hours, 48 hours,
1 week, ....

I will be detecting the temperature with a 15 minutes interval, so I will have 4 time-temperature values per hour.
Each room has an ID so the time-temperature values will be associated 
to the proper room.

The table I built i very simple:

```
----------------------------------
| ID |      DATE          | TEMP |
----------------------------------
| 1  |2014-04-30 00:00:00 | 18.6 |
----------------------------------
| 2  |2014-04-30 00:00:00 | 18.3 |
----------------------------------
| 3  |2014-04-30 00:00:00 | 18.3 |
----------------------------------
| 1  |2014-04-30 00:15:00 | 18.5 |
----------------------------------
```

For some strange reason, when the number of rows gets to 500 or so,the 
server becomes very slow.
Also, I have a web page were I can read the different temperatures of 
the rooms: this page polls the server through AJAX every 5 seconds (because it needs
to be frequently updated!), but when the number of rows of the table 
gets around 500, it hangs.

I tried to split the table and I created a table for each room, then a 
table for each time-window and now everything seems to be working fine.

Since I do not think this is the best/most efficient way to organize 
this thing, I need your help to give it a better structure.

I use a php script to retrieve the temperature data for all the rooms of my house:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM temperature t1 
          WHERE (id, date) IN 
          (SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM
          temperature t2 GROUP BY id)";
```

this query allows me to collect the temperature values in an array called $options:

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);             
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
$options [] = $rows;
}
```

then, I json-encode the array:

```
$j = json_encode($options);
```

and send it to the ajax script, which shows the data on the web page:

```
echo $j;
```

In the ajax script, I save the data in a variable and then parse it:

```
var return_data = xhr.responseText;
var temperature = JSON.parse(return_data);
```

next I loop through the array to extract the temperature values and put it in the right place on the web page:

```
for(var j=0; j<temperature.length; j++){
  document.getElementById("TEMPArea" + j).innerHTML = temperature[j].temp + "&deg;C";
}
```

This works fine as long as the rows in the 'temperature' table are less than 600 or so: polling every 5 seconds is not a problem.
Above 600, the page refresh gets slow and eventually it hangs and stops refreshing.

EDIT: Right now, I am working on a virtual machine with Windows 7 64bit, Apache, PHP and MySQL, 4GB RAM. Do you think this could be an issue?

Comment: A priori there's nothing wrong with a structure like the one you are showing, in database world a table with 500 rows is considered ridiculously small, and the fact that your system becomes extremely slow, to the point of totally hanging indicates that there's something very very wrong. Can you post some code and database schema?  Splitting up tables like you tried will merely hide these problems for some time, but will lead to huge structural problems that will infect your entire code.

Comment: Just to give you an idea: I'm looking here at a system that's basically a somewhat bigger version of what you want, with a measured values table containing 23 million rows of hundreds of measurement points.  Fetching the latest value for some random sensor takes around 11 milliseconds, fetching the latest 1000 values for some random sensor around 33 milliseconds...

Comment: are you bringing 500 rows to the browser? are you using paging?

Comment: @Tercol although this has the potential to be an interesting question, the complete lack of technical details about what you already tried put it at risk of being closed as too broad or unclear, so please add some code and details of the database.

Comment: @fvu, there isn't really much to add: I am such a newbie at this...My problem is that, as the amount of data I need grows, I start getting the "Maximum execution time of xx seconds exceeded" error. I know I can change the value of the execution time in php.ini (which I did), but I thought it had something to do with the database structure. I use php to fetch values.

Comment: @mschonaker, no I do not bring 500 lines to the browser. I only need 6 values, which are the latest from each room. Also, temperature is not the only thing I need to check, so I end up making multiple queries in a row, every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Tercol as I explained before, the load on the db to perform the task you describe should not even be noticeable. Hence, the key to the problem can be found in your code, but you seem reluctant to show it.  That is your choice, but it also means that short of *rewriting a complete a-z solution for you based on the litlte detail you provide* there's nothing useful that can be done here, and therefore I'm voting to close this question as lacking enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Tercol clarifications should be entered *into the question, and not as an answer*.  I moved them for you.  Next question: do you have any indexes on your table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was poor in details, so here's something more to what I said.

I use a php script to retrieve the temperature data for all the rooms of my house:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM temperature t1 
          WHERE (id, date) IN 
          (SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM
          temperature t2 GROUP BY id)";
```

this query allows me to collect the temperature values in an array called $options:

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);             
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
$options [] = $rows;
}
```

then, I json-encode the array:

```
$j = json_encode($options);
```

and send it to the ajax script, which shows the data on the web page:

```
echo $j;
```

In the ajax script, I save the data in a variable and then parse it:

```
var return_data = xhr.responseText;
var temperature = JSON.parse(return_data);
```

next I loop through the array to extract the temperature values and put it in the right place on the web page:

```
for(var j=0; j<temperature.length; j++){
  document.getElementById("TEMPArea" + j).innerHTML = temperature[j].temp + "&deg;C";
}
```

As I said in the first message, this works fine as long as the rows in the 'temperature' table are less than 600 or so: polling every 5 seconds is not a problem.
Above 600, the page refresh gets slow and eventually it hangs and stops refreshing.

I am not an expert, the code is pretty simple and straight forward, so I am having problems detecing the cause.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is the main source of problems:

- it's a slow way of getting the answer you want (you can always run it in Workbench and study the output of EXPLAIN - see [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-main-menu.html) for more details
- it implicitly supposes that all sensors with transmit at the same time, and as soon as that's not the case your output dataset won't be complete.  Normally you'll want the latest data from each individual sensor

so I propose a somewhat different approach:

1. add an index on date and one on id to speed up queries.  The lack of a PK is an issue, but let's first focus on solving the current issues...
2. obtain the list of available sensors - minimal solution

   ```
   select distinct id from temperature;
   ```

   but it would be better to store a list of available sensors in some other table - this query will also get slower as the number of records in temperature grows.
3. iterate over the results of that list to fetch the latest value for each of the sensors

   ```
   select * from temperature 
   where id = (value obtained in previous step) 
   order by date desc 
   limit 1;
   ```

   with this query you'll only get the most recent record associated with each sensor.  Thanks to the indexes, the speed impact of a growing table should be minimal.
4. reassemble these results in a data structure to send to your client web page.

Also, as stated in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), the mysql_* extension is **deprecated** and should **not be used in new programs**.  Use mysqli_ or preferably PDO.  Both these extensions will also allow you to use parameterized queries, the only **real** protection against [SQL Injection issues](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html).  See [here](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) for a quick introduction on how to use them

Comment: wow! That looks like advanced stuff to me! I am so new to this,  I will have to 'study' your answer for some time to understand it! There's one thing (among the others) that is not clear: how can a loop through the list of id's be faster than one single query? Thanks.

Comment: @Tercol take your time and don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.  Somewhat simplified, the reason is that some queries force the db-server to do very complicated or iterative work (eg by comparing all combinations of elements of 2 lists, the dreaded Cartesian product), and a sequence of more or less equivalent simple queries allow the server - eg helped by indexes - to get to a result much quicker without lots of searching and treating.